# copy paste excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have those sheets.
The second sheet is how I would it to be.
I am now trying for hours how I would do this.
Please can anyone help me on the right track.

I am copying from sheet 7(pic1) to sheet 9(pic2).
The lastrow to look for should be range F.

But I always end up like in pic3.

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: ?  The only difference I see between Picture2 and Picture3 is the spacing of the words "Chicken Italia" in Column A, but they don't appear at all on the sheet you say you are copying from.  Can you clarify what it is you are copying?

Comment: It would help us correct your code if we could actually see it.  Please paste it into the question.

Comment: It s like pic2 I try to make. But my result ends like pic3. 1 recipe name and several produce. So the 2nd recipe must be at the last row of produce list. I managed to get the space. Bu would like underline where a recipes ends. I ve tried with column end but no succes

Answer (score 1):

I can't see the pictures unfortunately, so I'm not sure how on the mark I am.

In general, you want to start something like this:

```
Sheets("Sheet 7").Activate
Range("A1:N8").Copy
Sheets("Sheet 9").Activate
Range("A1").Paste
```

To select your data, and move it over. Now let's get a bit fancy.

```
Dim I as long
Dim J as long
Dum K as long
Dim L as long

Dim O as long
Dim P as long
I = WorkSheetFunction.Vlookup(you know how a vlookup works)
J = WorksheetFunction.Sum(You really should know this one)
.....
P = 7
Sheets("Sheet 7").Activate
Range(I&J:O&P).Copy
Sheets("Sheet 9").Activate
Range(K&L).Paste
```

Where you can specify the starting and ending corner of your copy range, and the starting cell of your pasting range. Use macro recorder to find out exactly how a paste values, or other type of fancy paste works.

Comment: oow no pictures.

Comment: let me try like this. In column A i have the recipe name. From column B i have multiple rows of data. the ingredients. The second recipe, The recipe name should be below the several ingredients.

Answer (score 1):

this is the code i have for so far

```
Sub Test1()
Dim lrow As Long
Dim scr1 As Range 'source range
Dim scr2 As Range
Dim drng As Range 'destination range
Dim drng2 As Range
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Sheet7.Activate
Set drng = Sheet9.Range("A3")
Set drng2 = Sheet9.Range("D3")

Set scr1 = Sheet7.Range("RecipeHeader")
scr1.Select
Selection.Copy
Sheet9.Activate
drng.End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Sheet7.Activate
Set scr2 = Sheet7.Range("FoodCost_full")
scr2.Select
Selection.Copy
Sheet9.Activate
drng2.End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Sheet7.Range("ClearHeader").ClearContents
Sheet7.Range("Clearfood").ClearContents

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False


'lrow = Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Select

End Sub
```

Comment: You are better off including this in your original question.